# Why VSCode IntelliSense fails to highlight this Python import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense, or-tools

I'm using VSCode 1.70.1 with Python extension for Visual Studio Code v2022.12.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.1. I installed OR-Tools 9.3.10497 with 'pip'. These are all the modules installed:

```
Package    Version
---------- ---------
absl-py    1.2.0
cpmpy      0.9.9
numpy      1.23.1
ortools    9.3.10497
pip        22.2.2
protobuf   4.21.5
setuptools 58.1.0
```

Here is a screenshot from the editor:

[image]

Why the last line doesn't have IntelliSense highlighting? Why `Domain` doesn't have autocompletion?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the source code:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/util/python/sorted_interval_list.cc

`sorted_interval_list` is actually a binary/compiled python file generated with pybind11. And because ortools doesn't generate the corresponding stubs (for now) and VSCode doesn't do it automaticaly like PyCharm, IntelliSense does not work.

You can use tools like [stubgen](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html) to generate it yourself though.

PS: The problem is tracked in this [github discussion](https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3186)

Comment: That explains absence of autocompletion. Why `sorted_interval_list` is colored in line 2, but black in line 3? It suggests that `ortools.util.python.sorted_interval_list` module is not found.